# Adding SagePay payment module to Satchmo produces error

Tags: django, satchmo

I'm trying to add the SagePay module to Satchmo.  I've added 'payment.modules.sagepay' to my settings.py but when I go to mysite:8000/settings I get the following error:

```
Could not import payment.sagepay.checkout. Error was: No module named sagepay.checkout
```

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in my version of Satchmo, as documented at https://bitbucket.org/chris1610/satchmo/issue/1230/sagepay-error-in-urlspy